# Cannot manipulate with data property as an object if it is passed from parent to child component in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I tried to access passed object data property from parent compoent to child component but vue throws an exception that it cannot access them.
This my parent component

```
<app-full-name v-model="fullname"></app-full-name>
<script>
export default {
        components:{
            appFullName: FullName
        },
        data() {
            return {
                fullname: {
                  f:'Bassem',
                  l: 'Samir'
                },

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

in Child component

```
<script>
export default {
    props:['value'],
    methods: {
        changeName(isFirst, event){
            let name = "";
            if(isFirst){
                name = this.value.f+" ";
            }
            else{
                name = this.value.l+" "+this.value.l;
            }
        },  
    },
}
</script>
```

Vuejs throws an error that f property is undefined in child component.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `value`? And how does your `app-full-name` component look like?

Comment: When you get a props value, and pass a model, the data should reach the value property, I would recommend that you better organize this props statement. Ex: props: { value: { type: Object, default: () => {}}} if that doesn't work, I'd change the property name, and try to feed by passing information based on direct props. Ex: child: props: { myValue: { type: Object, default: () => {}}}, father: <app-full-name :my-value="fullname">

Answer (score 0):

You get an `undefined` because you are accessing a not defined prop 'value'. If you want to share data between parent->child, you should use:

```
//Parent file
<app-full-name your-data="fullname"></app-full-name>

//Child file (app-full-name)
...
props:['yourData']
```

This way you are sending to your child the 'your-data' as props. Remember that you can't change this value in the child, if you need to update it, you should do it via events (emit).

The child sends an event (emit it) and the parent is listening to do the propers changes in the data. Something like:

```
//child
this.$emit('changeData')

//parent
@changeData="changeData"
function changeData(){ //the changes here }
```

You could read more about it, [here](https://vegibit.com/vuejs-parent-child-communication/)

Hope it helps!